# Non-recursive formula for calculating the number of ways of arranging k elements in an n-element list so that no three elements are in adjacent cells?

Tags: combinatorics

While working on one problem, I've found myself solving a sub-problem like this recursively:

> We have a list of length $n$ consisting of $k$ ones and $n-k$ zeroes.
>   In how many ways can we rearrange the list so that the output list
>   does not have three or more ones one after another at any point?

For example, for a list $[0111]$ we could have $[1011]$ or $[1101]$ but not $[0111]$ or $[1110]$. Also, for $n=7$ and $k=5$, $[1100111]$ would be invalid but $[1101101]$ would be OK.

I've been doing this recursively building every possible string and then adding one when I've created a "correct" one but it got me wondering - is there some non-recursive formula which would allow counting this number?

Comment: See [OEIS A$082601$](http://oeis.org/A082601).

Comment: See also [OEIS A$078802$](http://oeis.org/A078802) and [OEIS A$078803$](http://oeis.org/A078803).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is still recursive, but doesn't involve actually constructing every sequence, so is much more efficient.  Let $f(n,k)$ denote the number of binary strings of length $n$ and density $k$ without $3$ consecutive $1$'s.  For $n\le 2$, we have $f(n,k)=\binom nk$.  For $n\ge 3$, we break these strings into $3$ sets according to whether the string ends in $0$, $01$, or $011$ (these are the only possibilities).  This leads to the recursion
$$f(n,k)=f(n-1,k) + f(n-2,k-1) + f(n-3,k-2).$$

The resulting table of values looks like this:
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 \text{} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
 0 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{}
   & \text{} & \text{} \\
 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} & \text{} \\
 3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
 4 & 1 & 4 & 6 & 2 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} &
   \text{} \\
 5 & 1 & 5 & 10 & 7 & 1 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 6 & 1 & 6 & 15 & 16 & 6 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 7 & 1 & 7 & 21 & 30 & 19 & 3 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 8 & 1 & 8 & 28 & 50 & 45 & 16 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 9 & 1 & 9 & 36 & 77 & 90 & 51 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \text{} \\
 10 & 1 & 10 & 45 & 112 & 161 & 126 & 45 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: See [OEIS A$082601$](http://oeis.org/A082601), [OEIS A$078802$](http://oeis.org/A078802), and [OEIS A$078803$](http://oeis.org/A078803).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why do we know the string always ends in 0, 01, or 011, though? Can't a string of length 1 end in 1 as well as 0?

Comment: @Straightfw The case of a $1$-long string is handled in the "base case" of the recursion (that was $n\le 2$ here).  The breakdown into cases applies to strings of length $n\ge 3$.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks a lot :)